# Get page slug and assign a variable within functions.php

Tags: functions, slug

I have created a lazy loading script using AJAX and JSON for my blog. It works perfectly. However I have 4 different blogs on the same site. These are created using custom post types.

I need to get the AJAX to do lazy loading for all of these blogs. I can get it to work for each one by manually changing the name from post to boutiques for example.

So I created a variable called $postname and want to assign this a different value depending on the slug of the page you are on when you click load more posts.

How can i check what page slug is and then assign my variable a name. Here is my code but I need to know how to call the slug of the page im on and assign that to $slug.

```
if ( $slug == 'boutiques'  ) {

    $postname = 'boutiques';

} elseif ( $slug == 'tourist' ) {

    $postname = 'tourist';
}
else {
    $postname = 'post';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

assuming you are properly adding the AJAX script to your theme via [`wp_enqueue_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script), you can pass data to the script via [`wp_localize_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script), which you should already be using to pass the path to `admin-ajax.php` if you are using AJAX correctly within your plugin or theme.

see the [Codex page on AJAX](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) for more info. [this tutorial](http://www.garyc40.com/2010/03/5-tips-for-using-ajax-in-wordpress/) linked at the bottom of that page has all the examples you'll need.

a purely javascript solution (which I don't recommend) would be to use the [location object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp) to determine context.